# Can't clone git repo by vpn

Tags: git, vpn

I'm trying to clone a project from an external repository using a VPN, because this project is located on the work, so i can't get simple access to it. When i input

```
  `git clone https://192.168.1.8/myproject`
```

i'm get error `Failed to connected to localhost port 9150: Connection refused`

Comment: Do you need certain proxy permissions to be able to do this?

Comment: Can you try like this:-> `git clone https://192.168.1.8:9150/myproject` 
It may work for you.

Comment: @pRaNaY, it didn't work :(

Comment: @BrianaSwift, how can i chek this permisson? May be i must type some comands in git?

Comment: It would have to do with your work VPN. If you have access to GitHub.com, you can test by creating a remote repository there, then cloning locally and trying to push.

Comment: @BrianaSwift im successfully create repo and done commit and push. So, trouble in other things.

Comment: ok, i have next one trouble. 

Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)